# Corona sdk scoring?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a scoring system that displays an all time score across every scene, when a user completes a scene the score from that scene is added to the all time score.

I get 1 error in the compiler: Attempt to perform "arithmetic" on field "score"

code from main lua: contains no errors but not sure if correct.
    
    `-- 1 Clue 1 Word`

```
display.setStatusBar (display.HiddenStatusBar)

local storyboard = require ( "storyboard" )
storyboard.gotoScene("menu") 

storyboard.state = {}
storyboard.state.score = 0
storyboard.state.score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 250, 20, "ARIAL", 16)

<code>
```

The error appears in the line: storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 1

```
<code>
if(correct == #L1) then
    --alert()
    print ("CORRECT "..#L1)
    line.isVisible = false
    storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 500)
    storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 1
    storyboard.removeScene( "scene1" )
end


end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `storyboard.state.score` assigned  twice?

```
storyboard.state.score = 0
storyboard.state.score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 250, 20, "ARIAL", 16)
```

---

**UPD :**

```
storyboard.state = {score = 0}
score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 250, 20, "ARIAL", 16) 

storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 500) 
storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 1 
storyboard.removeScene( "scene1" )
```

Comment: I did that so it displayed the score, my bad, I'm guessing i was supposed to do score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 250, 20, "ARIAL", 16) or something like that?

Comment: What i did worked but the score doesn't go up by on on the text, heres the new code:                                          storyboard.state = {}
storyboard.state.score = 0
score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 250, 20, "ARIAL", 16)
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 500)
  score = storyboard.state.score + 1
  storyboard.removeScene( "scene1" )
    end
 
 
    end
end

Comment: The code you gave me still doesn't change the score in the top right corner, the simulator knows the score though because when i print it in the simulator output it prints score: 1, i've been doing a bit of research but cannot find anything, it should be just a score that goes up in each scene so by the time they are level 10 they will have a score of 10...

Comment: @ZacBaker - After incrementing counter you should create new image and display it.